# X++ Exception details

Tags: axapta, x++

Is it possible to have the exception detail of an exception raised in AX?
What I am trying to do is to emulate the behaviour of the exceptions in C#.

I am working with AX, so an AX related exception would be great, but even taking the most general exception would be much better than no error text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When AX throws an error it is of type Exception. This is an enum with a number of different types which are listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exception.aspx. 
This is pretty much all the info you get. The error message is in the infolog, but there is no relation to the exception.

Quote from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc967369.aspx:

> In X++ the message that is created when an exception is raised is available only in the Infolog, and the message is not directly tied to the exception. In C# the message is the Message member of the System.Exception object.

You can however catch the different kinds of exceptions separately as demonstrated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa893385.aspx

For exceptions coming from clr, you can get the inner exception with the message (see: http://daxmusings.codecrib.com/2013/04/exception-handling-in-dynamics-ax.html)

An extendable Exception class in AX would be great, who knows in future versions...

Comment: Hi Klaas, so my best shot would be to concatenate a long series of catch clauses and use a fixed string related to the current exception be the error message?

Comment: I'd say use exception handling as-is in Dynamics AX. What exactly are you trying to achieve that is not possible with the way it works in AX? Exception handling in AX is focused on making sure data integrity is respected by rolling back transactions. When an error is thrown, the transaction is rolled back and the user gets a message on which he/she can act. There is little you can do in your catch when everything is rolled back. If there is, you probably shouldn't have thrown that exception in the first place.